# Thread Pool handling 'duplicate' tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to be executing some different tasks in parallel, but have the concept that if a task is already queued or is currently processing, it will not get re-queued.  I have read up a little on the Java API and have come up with the code below, which seems to work.
Can anybody shed light on whether the method I am using is the best approach.  Any dangers (thread safety?)  or better ways to do this?
Code is as below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestExecution implements Runnable {
   String key1;
   String key2;   
   static HashMap<TestExecution, Future<?>> executions = new HashMap<TestExecution, Future<?>>();
   static LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
   static ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 5, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, q);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         execute(new TestExecution("A", "A"));
         execute(new TestExecution("A", "A"));
         execute(new TestExecution("B", "B"));
         Thread.sleep(8000);
         execute(new TestExecution("B", "B"));
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   static boolean execute(TestExecution e) {
      System.out.println("Handling "+e.key1+":"+e.key2);
      if (executions.containsKey(e)) {
         Future<?> f = (Future<?>) executions.get(e);
         if (f.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Previous execution has completed");
            executions.remove(e);
         } else {
            System.out.println("Previous execution still running");
            return false;
         }         
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("No previous execution");
      }
      Future<?> f = tpe.submit(e);
      executions.put(e, f);            
      return true;
   }

   public TestExecution(String key1, String key2) {
      this.key1 = key1;
      this.key2 = key2;      
   }

   public boolean equals(Object obj)
   {
       if (obj instanceof TestExecution)
       {
          TestExecution t = (TestExecution) obj;
           return (key1.equals(t.key1) && key2.equals(t.key2));           
       }       
       return false;
   }

   public int hashCode ()
   {
      return key1.hashCode()+key2.hashCode();
   }

   public void run() {      
      try {
         System.out.println("Start processing "+key1+":"+key2);
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         System.out.println("Finish processing "+key1+":"+key2);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }      
   }              
}
```

Follow up to comment below:
The plan is that triggering the tasks to execute will be handled by cron calling RESTful web service. For example below is the setup for one task triggered at 9:30 every day, plus another scheduled every two minutes.

```
0/2 * * * * restclient.pl key11 key12 
30 09 * * * restclient.pl key21 key22
```

In this case, if task key11:key12 is running, or already queued to run, I don't want to queue another instance. I understand we have other options for scheduling, however we tend to use cron for other tasks, so I want to try to keep this.

Second Update.  In response to comments so far I have re-written the code, could you comment on any issues with the following updated solution?

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class TestExecution implements Runnable {
   String key1;
   String key2;      
   static TestThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new TestThreadPoolExecutor(new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         tpe.execute(new TestExecution("A", "A"));
         tpe.execute(new TestExecution("A", "A"));
         tpe.execute(new TestExecution("B", "B"));
         Thread.sleep(8000);
         tpe.execute(new TestExecution("B", "B"));
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public TestExecution(String key1, String key2) {
      this.key1 = key1;
      this.key2 = key2;      
   }

   public boolean equals(Object obj)
   {
       if (obj instanceof TestExecution)
       {
          TestExecution t = (TestExecution) obj;
           return (key1.equals(t.key1) && key2.equals(t.key2));           
       }       
       return false;
   }

   public int hashCode ()
   {
      return key1.hashCode()+key2.hashCode();
   }

   public void run() {      
      try {
         System.out.println("Start processing "+key1+":"+key2);
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         System.out.println("Finish processing "+key1+":"+key2);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }      
   }
}


import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class TestThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   Set<Runnable> executions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Runnable>());

   public TestThreadPoolExecutor(LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> q) {      
      super(2, 5, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, q);      
   }

   public void execute(Runnable command) {
      if (executions.contains(command)) {
         System.out.println("Previous execution still running");
         return;
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("No previous execution");
      }
      super.execute(command);      
      executions.add(command);      
   }

   protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
      super.afterExecute(r, t);        
      executions.remove(r);
   }      
}
```

Comment: Why not use a hashset for TestExecution instead of HashMap??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of comments:

- in the execute-method, you will get a race-condition between the reading of "executions" (containsKey) and the writing (remove or put) if several threads call this method at the same time.  You need to wrap all calls to "executions" which are supposed to be atomic in a synchronized-block. (In your case, making the method synchronized will work) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html
- You should handle state using a singleton rather than static (i.e. global) variables

But I really would like to know a bit more about your design to understand what you are trying to achieve.  Why would a task be queued for execution several times?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with some more information.

Comment: And for a more object oriented design, I would consider subclassing ThreadPoolExecutor and putting the code for managing the executions-map in the execute() and afterExecute()-functions. (It also seems to me to be more correct to call execute() rather than submit(), but the spec is not explicit on this point)

Comment: Cheers, have rewritten code based on your suggestions.  Does that seem any better?

Comment: you seem to have avoided the race-condition by using atomic instructions of the ConcurrentHashMap (I must say a more elegant solution than adding "synchronized" to executions()).  The TestThreadPoolExecutor is also good, this encapsulates all queue-handling code in the Executor and avoids global variables.  For a final touch you could add checs for null in the TestExecution constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I would handle and avoid duplicates

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TestExecution implements Callable<Void> {
    private static final ThreadPoolExecutor TPE = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 5, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    private static final Set<TestExecution> TE_SET = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<TestExecution, Boolean>());

    private final String key1;
    private final String key2;

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        new TestExecution("A", "A").execute();
        new TestExecution("A", "A").execute();
        new TestExecution("B", "B").execute();
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        new TestExecution("A", "A").execute();
        new TestExecution("B", "B").execute();
        new TestExecution("B", "B").execute();
        TPE.shutdown();
    }

    public TestExecution(String key1, String key2) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    void execute() {
        if (TE_SET.add(this)) {
            System.out.println("Handling " + this);
            TPE.submit(this);
        } else {
            System.out.println("... ignoring duplicate " + this);
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof TestExecution &&
                key1.equals(((TestExecution) obj).key1) &&
                key2.equals(((TestExecution) obj).key2);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return key1.hashCode() * 31 + key2.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        if (!TE_SET.remove(this)) {
            System.out.println("... dropping duplicate " + this);
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Start processing " + this);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.out.println("Finish processing " + this);
        return null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return key1 + ':' + key2;
    }
}
```

prints

```
Handling A:A
... ignoring duplicate A:A
Handling B:B
Start processing A:A
Start processing B:B
Finish processing A:A
Finish processing B:B
Handling A:A
Handling B:B
Start processing A:A
Start processing B:B
... ignoring duplicate B:B
Finish processing B:B
Finish processing A:A
```

Comment: OK, thanks, some good pointers there, especially avoiding multithreading issues by using ConcurrentHashMap and overriding the toString method.  A couple of questions.  Why not use HashSet (is that because there is no equivalent thread safe object to use?)  Also I don't understand the code for removal from the HashMap.  You seem to do this at the start of the processing, shouldn't that be at the end of processing?

Comment: You can use `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet())`  This is thread safe, but not concurrent.  Whether its at the start or the end depends on your requirements. Is it better to occasionally do something twice or occasionally not doing something (because the new task was added between the task ending and being removed)

Comment: OK, I don't really know the difference between 'thread safe' and 'concurrent', maybe I have some investigation to do there.  But for removing the element, if I don't want to re-execute (or queue) a job that has already started, then the TE_SET.remove should be moved to the end of the Call function, right?  Am I correct in assuming the "dropping duplicate" case is an error case?  If we are in the call function, then an element should always have been written to the HashSet right?

Comment: My definition: Thread safe means it has a predictable and consistent state when used by multiple threads. BTW: This doesn't have to mean locking. Concurrent means it can be used by multiple threads without blocking each other.

Comment: You can move to the end, but you have a race condition that it could have finished, or be partly finished, but still in the collection.  Do you still want it to not run in this case?  "dropping duplicates" detects race conditions, but doesn't have to be an error.  I don't know what you mean by your last question.

Comment: If task  is processing, (represented by the 4 second sleep in this test case) I don't want to queue or process another execution.  If the task has just finished processing, but the element not yet removed from the collection, then I am not concerned if the task does not execute.  To try to clarify my last statement, I mean during the normal course of operation, "dropping duplicate" should not be displayed, because if we are in the 'call()' method we must have got there due to the submit() method being called, so the add() to the collection must have succeeded.

Comment: Placing it last is what you want.  For the systems I work on, a rare duplicate is better than dropping a task.